# Array of images in canvas not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

Could someone please help to make the below code work. also is there any other way to display the images without using onload?

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            c.width = $(document).width();
            c.height = $(document).height();
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var imgArray = new Array();

            imgArray[0] = new Image();
            imgArray[1] = new Image();
            imgArray[0].src = "1.png";
            imgArray[1].src = "2.png";
            var x = 30;
            var y = 40;
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                imgArray[i].onload = function () {


                    ctx.drawImage(imgArray[i], x, y);

                }
                x = x + 20;
            } 
        });

    </script>  
</head>
```

I want images to be displayed on canvas using array. it works fine if i use array without for loop. please help in fixing the issue.

```
<body style="margin:0; height:100%; width:100%; overflow:hidden;" >  
 <canvas id="myCanvas"  style="display:block; "   >
     Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you try removing the onload event in the for? It makes no sense. Technically, Jquery's ready function is already taking care of it.

Comment: Doesn't work how? There are several issues, as in the source should be set after the onload function, and the value of x will change before the images load etc.

Comment: @JesusZamora - That not the right answer, why would document.ready know when two javascript images are ready and loaded ?

Comment: What's happening is that the for function finalizes before the onload function triggers. What you should do is make sure the files are ready, THEN you load them.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I have to display various images on canvas. Images will be created in javascript. @JesusZamora I have tried without onload , it still remains the same, there is something wrong in using for loop only and i cant figure out what that is

Comment: @adeneo source does not make a difference before or after. I have tried both ways

Comment: See my answer below. Can you not do it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice to define a function within a loop. Try defining it outside of the loop with a named function. Also it'd probably be better to set the src of the img after the `onload` function is attached. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    c.width = $(document).width();
    c.height = $(document).height();
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var imgArray = new Array();

    imgArray[0] = new Image();
    imgArray[1] = new Image();
    var x = 30;
    var y = 40;

    function onImageLoad() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, x, y);
        x = x + 20;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        imgArray[i].onload = onImageLoad;
    } 

    imgArray[0].src = "1.png";
    imgArray[1].src = "2.png";
});
```

If you must have the loop in the function (which you don't), you would need to wrap it within a closure so that each image gets it's own onload function instead of defining the same function which is what happens in your case.

Something similar to the following would probably work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    imgArray[i].onload = (function(idx) {
        return function() {
            ctx.drawImage(imgArray[idx], x, y);
            x = x + 20;
        }
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: Still cant see the images

Comment: Sorry added a `this` reference in the onImageLoad function. Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/fbqh5/

Answer (score 0):

This is how you *could* do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Source
    var imgArray = new Array();
    imgArray[0] = new Image();
    imgArray[1] = new Image();
    imgArray[0].src = "http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/963/very_emotional_emoticons/64/64_18.png";
    imgArray[1].src = "http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/963/very_emotional_emoticons/64/64_30.png";

    // Draw Images
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var startX = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        ctx.drawImage(imgArray[i], startX, 0);
        startX += 74;
    }
});

</script>

<canvas id="myCanvas"  style="display:block;">
     Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Outputs:

[image]

---

P.S. The images are `64x64` (width x height). So to draw them next to each other with 10px spacing, I add 10 to 64 (width), hence I do `startX += 74;` and the images draw like that.

You should be able to modify this code to meet your own needs.

Comment: It does not display the images.

Comment: You're forgetting to handle onload which may result in images not showing. Image loading is async and therefor onload must be handled.